# Index entries and ancient Greek language

Tags: polyglossia, greek, sorting, imakeidx

I'm using the package `polyglossia` and I'm building the index with `imakeidx`. One index, which contains greek words, does not follow the correct alphabetical order.
How could I do to get a correct alphabetical order?
Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{times.ttf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{times.ttf}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\makeindex[name=1]

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}{ἀγαθός, καλός, δεινός, μείγνυμι}


\index[1]{ἀγαθός} 
\index[1]{καλός}
\index[1]{δεινός} 
\index[1]{μείγνυμι}

\printindex[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the symbol over `α` meddles with the sorting algorithm. A possible solution would be to use `\index[1]{αγαθος@ἀγαθός}` instead of `\index[1]{ἀγαθός}`. In this way the entry will appear as `ἀγαθός` but will be sorted as `αγαθος`. Greetings from Greece!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{times.ttf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{times.ttf}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\makeindex[name=1]
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}{ἀγαθός, καλός, δεινός, μείγνυμι}
\index[1]{αγαθος@ἀγαθός}
\index[1]{καλός}
\index[1]{δεινός} 
\index[1]{μείγνυμι}
\printindex[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine!